# Mvn install Error while processing pom.xml

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

I have a maven project that I want to go live on the server.
For the first time, I'm going to live a project with tomcat, for this, I set up tomcat by making the necessary settings.xml and pom.xml settings from some sources on the internet.But
when I write mvn install tomcat:deploy on the command line to deploy my maven project via tomcat, I encounter the following error

[image]

updated error : [image]
pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        
<version>2.5.4</version>

<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>      <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>level3</groupId>
    <artifactId>reports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>reports</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
           <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
           <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


<plugin>
    
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            
<artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            
<version>2.0</version>
            
<configuration>
        
    <server>maven-tomcat-war-deployment-server</server>
        
    <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
            
<path>/reports</path>
            
</configuration>
    
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have no idea what is the error . How could I change to pom.xml ?

Comment: This `<relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> ` should be `</relativePath>` instead.... BTW: Don't post pictures better use text...

Comment: Unfortunately I can't see or copy the whole error, I don't have permission to do so, so I posted it as a picture, I also did as you said, but it still didn't work.

Comment: And the error output...while you checked via `mvn clean package` ? And what have done in your `settings.xml`?

Comment: yes I checked and encountered same error , I have done  tomcat user control in settings.xml

Comment: how can u still have the same error if you have changed your pom.xml to use correct <relativePath/> ? please post updated error message

Comment: I posted error message